# Static Array of string must be converted from database

Tags: java, android

this might be a long message but i would like to give a clear question for all of stackoverflow user.
What I did is create a static String of array inside a class that is binded on my gridview

```
class ParserArrayList {
       //some declaration and codes here
      private String [] imageCaptionId = {
        "My First Medal",
        "You ...",
        "The ...",
        "Gimme ...",
        "A ...",
        "Seven ...",
        ".....City",
        ".... Madness",
        "Loyal...",
        ".....",
        "...",
        "Champion..."
        };
}
```

And manually binding it on public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
//some declaration and variables here
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v;

        ParserArrayList arrayImage = new ParserArrayList();
        String[] imagetext = arrayImage.getImageCaptionId(); 
        if (convertView == null) {
        //some stuff here
        }
//some stuff here
return v;
}
```

As you see I am calling ParserArrayList's 'imageCaptionId' and sends it to another string of array in which i declare 'imagetext '

Everything works fine until I found out that the array 'imageCaptionId' must be based on local database
Ive tried using this code but I cant finish because

```
class ParserArrayList {
//added this code
public SQLiteAdapter sqlAdapter;
//and this one
public void showData(){
    sqlAdapter = new SQLiteAdapter(this);

    String str = "Select dTitle from achievement_tb where version =0 order by ID ASC;";

    sqlAdapter.openToRead();

    Cursor c =sqlAdapter.read(str);

    sqlAdapter.close();
}
}
```

First: I dont know how to bind it to array

Second: I created it inside ParserArrayList and it gives me an error saying
**The constructor SQLiteAdapter(ParserArrayList) is undefined** (This is already done)

Could you help me sir

**EDIT**
This is what I am trying to accomplish or my logic

on my ParserArrayList class I am trying to add this code (I dont know if this is correct)

```
    public String[] showImageCaption(){
    String imageCaptionIds [];
    sqlAdapter = new SQLiteAdapter(mContext);

    String str = "Select dTitle from achievement_tb where version =0 order by ID ASC;";

    sqlAdapter.openToRead();

    Cursor c =sqlAdapter.read(str);     
    imageCaptionIds [c.getCount()];

    sqlAdapter.close();
    return imageCaptionIds;
}
```

which gives me an error saying **Syntax error, insert "AssignmentOperator Expression" to complete Expression**

now on my ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter here is my codes

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v;
        ParserArrayList arrayImage = new ParserArrayList(mContext);
        newArrayList2 = arrayImage.getArraylist();
        **String[] imagetext = arrayImage.showImageCaption();** 
        if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
             LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();
             v = li.inflate(R.layout.medal_grid, null);
        }
        else
        {
             v = convertView;
        }
        TextView tv = (TextView)
        v.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_label);
        **tv.setText(imagetext[position]);**
        ImageView iv = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);
        iv.setImageResource((Integer) newArrayList2.get(position));
        return v;
    }
```

My logic is that I will bind it on my array of String inside ParserArrayList (in which it will return imageCaptionIds) and set it on a textview

Comment: Hope someone can answer this question cause i might encountered it also ^_^

Comment: the second problem occurs because you are passing the wrong parameter to `sqlAdapter = new SQLiteAdapter(this);`. Your `this` refer to `ParserArrayList` (which is an object you created), you should create an `SQLiteOpenHelper` to access you database. See [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html)

Comment: ill try reading your article sir

Comment: if you can access your database, binding data to array should not be a problem, good luck.

Comment: @AndRoyd added another tutorial (IMO, this is easier to understand than Vogelle's version): http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand the first question, but the second one is easy.

You need to pass a Context (or a class that extends Context, like an Activity) to `new SQLiteAdapter()`. Simply change your ParserArrayList to match this:

```
public class ParserArrayList {
    Context mContext;
    ...

    public ParserArrayList(Context context) { 
        mContext = context;
        ... 
    }

    public void showData(){
        sqlAdapter = new SQLiteAdapter(mContext);
        ...
    }
}
```

Inside your Activity, perhaps onCreate(), simply call:

```
 ParserArrayList pal = new ParserArrayList(this);
```

---

I'll attempt to answer the first question. Why **must** your String array be put into a `SQLiteDatabase`? An `ArrayAdapter<String>` works quite well with String arrays...  Why won't something like this work?

```
public class ImageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    //some declaration and variables here

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v;

        String imagetext = getItem(position); // returns the caption at index
        if (convertView == null) {
            //some stuff here
        }

        //some stuff here
        return v;
    }
}
```

With a declaration:

```
private String [] imageCaptionId = { ... };
ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(this, R.layout.awesome, imageCaptionId);
```

Comment: Sir this is what I am trying to accomplish. Please see me edited codes above

Comment: is my logic possible sir? Please see it now

Comment: ok sir I think i will recreate my logic based on your answer.. Thanks for your reply ^_^

Comment: I looked at your new code and you don't read the Cursor yet. However if you are trying my approach then this doesn't matter. I encourage you to watch this lecture by Android's [Romain Guy on Adapters and getView()](http://www.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/TurboChargeUiAndroidFast.html). Good luck!